# Java Properties File not loading

Tags: java, properties

I need a configuration file in my program to store some information, I saw some examples of properties files and was trying to use them but whenever I try this second line on NetBeans i get 'Package sortConfig doesn't exist' '`<identifier`> Expected' and 'Illegal start of type'.

The problem is I already saw some 10 examples all doing this in the same way, and I have no clue to what's going on.

```
Properties sortConfig = new Properties();

sortConfig.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sortConfig.properties"));
```

Any help would be appreciated

my .java classes and my properties file are on the src, inside the same package folder

Comment: Where is sortConfig.properties located? Can you please add your package structure?

Comment: You seem to be getting a compile error, but it doesn't make sense. The two lines compile fine, they must be misplaced or whatever. Provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the fully qualified path to your properties file. You can get to it in 2 ways:-

1. Using java.util.ResourceBundle:

> ResourceBundle bundle
>   =ResourceBundle.getBundle("br.com.example.sortConfig");
>   //.properties is implied

or

1. Using ClassLoader.getResouceAsStream:

> ```
> sortConfig.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("br/com/example/sortConfig.propertie"));
> ```

For a good tutorial on how to load properties files resources check out this [link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html).

Comment: the ClassLoader didn't work, but the ResourceBundle worked beautifully so I didn't bother, Thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` which accepts relative pathnames (relative to the package your class is in, that is), so you could simply write

```
sortConfig.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sortConfig.properties"));
```

This is useful when you specifically want to rely on your class and properties file being in the same package. (So when you move one during a refactoring, you'll have to move the other too.)